# Vis.js - how to prevent dragging after double click on a node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vis.js-network

With my Vis.js network I've got an even listener to catch double click on a node.

PROBLEM: once I double click a node, it starts being dragged. Somehow node drag starts and node is glued to the mouse coursor until mouse click. How can this be prevented?

On double click I get the id of clicked node, next I get adjacent nodes and for each one I call a function to add them to an Array.

Then I call nodes.update() - and all works great. Except for the dragging that I have no idea where is it coming from.

```
            // initialize the network!
        network = new vis.Network(container, data, getOptions(networkLayout));
        network.fit();

        // add event listener for double click on node
        network.on("doubleClick", function (params) {
            // get the id of the clicked node
            var clickedNodeId = params.nodes[0];
            var nodesToUpdate = [];

            // get the adjacent nodes of the clicked node
            var adjacentNodes = network.getConnectedNodes(clickedNodeId);

            adjacentNodes.forEach(addAdjacentNodesToUpdate);
            function addAdjacentNodesToUpdate(nodeId, index) {
                nodesToUpdate.push({id: nodeId, hidden: false, physics: true});
            }
            nodes.update(nodesToUpdate);
            showHideEdges(nodesToUpdate);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been some kind of browser glitch. It worked fine on another machine, so I went back to the first one and did the usual: tried a different browser, tried private mode, cleared cache - it's working fine now, the issue is gone. Just made me lose some time.